# Can the constructor of a base class be called from a non-constructor method in the derived class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

Consider this derived class `D` whose constructor calls the base class constructor -

```
class D extends Map{constructor(){super([[1, 'a']])}}
```

we can test it with

```
const d = new D
d.get(1) // returns 'a' as expected
```

but if I define instance method `init()` in derived class `D` to call the base class constructor -

```
class D extends Map{init(){super([[1, 'a']])}}
```

I receive error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
```

Can the constructor of a base class be called from a non-constructor method in the derived class?

Comment: Did you mean `return new super.constructor(…)`?

Comment: @Bergi I tried your suggestion but then `d.init()` returns `Map` instead updating the base class of `D`. I wanted `d.get(1)` to return `a`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You cannot re-construct an already constructed object?! If you want to add entries to an existing `Map` instance, use `.set()`.

Comment: @Bergi I thought it might be possible since [it is possible to mutate any member of the prototype chain or even swap out the prototype at runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain). Thanks for answering

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the constructor does? It initialises the state of one instance.